# Can't integrated a pen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like copy a custom select box from here --> https://codepen.io/microfront/pen/NXGrGQ  into my website,
but it's not work when I paste the whole code.
I can't figure out how. I tried to copy all the html, css and java but doesn't work, then I even tried to convert scss to css still not working

I have this result from any navigator [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5OoD.png)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto 60px;
  max-width: 600px;
}


/*Chosen style*/

.chosen-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.chosen-wrapper:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  z-index: 9;
}

.chosen-wrapper.is-active:after {
  border-top: 8px solid black;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container .chosen-single {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 70px;
  border: solid 2px #d9d9d9;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0 30px;
  line-height: 66px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #fff;
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container .chosen-single b {
  display: none !important;
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container .chosen-single span {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single {
  border-width: 2px 2px 1px;
  border-color: #000 #000 #d9d9d9;
  color: #000;
  background-image: none;
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container.chosen-container-single-nosearch .chosen-search {
  display: none;
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container .chosen-drop {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px;
  border-color: #000;
  margin-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  opacity: 0;
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container .chosen-results {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  max-height: 245px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container .chosen-results li {
  padding: 16px 30px 18px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  line-height: 20px;
}

.chosen-wrapper .chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted {
  background-color: #eeeeee !important;
  color: #000;
  background-image: none;
}

.chosen-wrapper--style2:after {
  right: 0;
}

.chosen-wrapper--style2:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.06, 1, 0.89, 0.85);
}

.chosen-wrapper--style2.is-active:before {
  width: 100%;
}

.chosen-wrapper--style2 .chosen-container .chosen-single {
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
}

.chosen-wrapper--style2 .chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single {
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
}

.chosen-wrapper--style2 .chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.chosen-wrapper--style2 .chosen-container .chosen-drop {
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-top: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.chosen-wrapper--style2 .chosen-container .chosen-results li {
  padding: 16px 15px 18px;
}


/*ScrollBox style*/

.nicescroll-rails {
  border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  transform: translate(-2px);
  top: 0 !important;
}

.nicescroll-rails .nicescroll-cursors {
  width: 6px !important;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.link {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.link a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.link .fa {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Responsive custom select box</h1>

<!--Style 2-->
<div class="chosen-wrapper chosen-wrapper--style2">
  <select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
    <option></option>
    <option>Consectetur adipiscing</option>
    <option>Sed do eiusmod tempor</option>
  </select>
</div>
```